# Partial implementation of parsing a config-file and command line options

Tags: python, parsing

I need to be able to accept some options from either the command-line or a config-file.

This code is a snippet of the class that I am working on, I cannot post the entire class here. This code works, but I am wondering if it can be made better. I will need to have a class here, there is a lot more work that goes on in the real code, I have pulled out just the parsing stuff. Please note, there are also several more sub-parsers that I will need, but the sub-parser shown is the only one that will possibly use a config file.

There is an issue with argparse with nesting argument_groups and mutually_exclusive_groups. So, I am not trying to use mutually-exclusive, but I am checking that with my own code in the functions.

```
import argparse
import yaml
from pprint import pprint

_possible_config_file_keys = ('names', 'ids')

class Parser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.build_parser()
        self.options = self.parse_args()
        #do other stuff here using self.options

    def build_parser(self):
        self.root_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Tool for ...")
        self.root_sub_parsers = self.root_parser.add_subparsers(dest='action')
        self.add_person_parser()
        self.add_other_parser()

    def add_person_parser(self):
        parser = self.root_sub_parsers.add_parser('People')
        g = parser.add_argument_group('People Targets')
        g.add_argument(
            "--config-file",
            help='Supply a config file',
            type=argparse.FileType(mode='r'))
        g.add_argument('--name', dest='names', default=[], action='append')
        g.add_argument('--id', dest='ids', default=[], action='append')

    def add_other_parser(self):
        pass #would do actual work here and add more subparsers

    def parse_args(self):
        args = self.parse_command_line_args()
        if args.config_file:
            self.parse_config_file(args)
        delattr(args, 'config_file')

        #I must ensure that 'Bob' is in the list of names
        if 'Bob' not in args.names:
            args.names.append('Bob')
        return args

    def parse_command_line_args(self):
        return self.root_parser.parse_args()

    def parse_config_file(self, args):
        self.check_args(args)
        data = yaml.load(args.config_file)
        args.config_file.close()
        for key, value in data.items():
            if key not in _possible_config_file_keys:
                self.root_parser.error("Invalid key '{}' in config file".format(key))
            if isinstance(value, str):
                value = [value, ]
            setattr(args, key, value)

    def check_args(self, args):
        invalid_keys = [
            key for key in vars(args).keys() if key in _possible_config_file_keys
            and getattr(args, key)]
        if invalid_keys:
            self.root_parser.error("Cannot use config-file keys along with config-file")

#For my testing purpose
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = Parser()
    pprint(vars(parser.options))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good practice to set all of the instance attributes you need in `__init__`; moving across the contents of `build_parser` into `__init__` would only add three lines!

---

It seems a bit... roundabout, in places. For example, `__init__` calls `parse_args` which calls `parse_command_line_args` which calls the `root_parser`'s `parse_args`. At the very least, I would roll the call to `self.root_parser.parse_args` into `parse_args`, as then you aren't going back and forth between method names as you follow the logic through.

---

There is an unexplained "magic string" in the middle of it all:

```
#I must ensure that 'Bob' is in the list of names
if 'Bob' not in args.names:
    args.names.append('Bob')
```

The comment just says *what* the code is doing, but doesn't explain *why*, so it's redundant. In general, you have no explanations of the logic - [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) would be helpful.

---

Some of those functions seem like implementation detail, rather than functionality you want to expose, so I would prefix the names with underscores to indicate *private-by-convention*, e.g. `_add_person_parser` and `_add_other_parser`.

---

I would make `_possible_config_file_keys = ('names', 'ids')` a *class attribute* of `Parser`, and indicate it as constant using the [style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) naming conventions, i.e.

```
class Parser(object):

    POSSIBLE_CONFIG_FILE_KEYS = ('names', 'ids')

    ...
```

---

You only seem to use `pprint` for testing, so I would move that `import` into the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. Also, there should be a blank line between standard library and third-party imports:

```
import argparse

import yaml
```

---

Do you not need to `check_args` in cases where you *don't* `parse_config_file`? Again, some documentation to explain that logic would be helpful.